# Using MPMoviePlayerController with a self-signed cert

Tags: ios, ssl, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to stream an HLS stream over HTTPS with a self-signed cert. I get the following error:

```
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

Is there any way to tell MPMoviePlayerController to trust this cert? I'm working on getting the cert signed by a trusted authority, but it might take awhile.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer outside of installing the cert on the device?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I remember I didn't end up using MPMoviePlayerController for my project. May want to see if installing the self-signed cert on the device works, as Wagner pointed out below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just send the self-signed certificate to your e-mail (an e-mail setup in the device). Then, just tap on the certificate and then you will be able to add it to your device.

PS: You must use the Apple Mail client. If you try it with other clients [like GMail client], it won't work.